# Mock private method in Grails

Tags: grails, integration-testing, spock

I am novice to grails and experiencing difficulty with integration testing.I have a service class which internally calls an external service from a private method.  Is there any way to mock this private method so that i can avoid the external service call for integration test? Please guide me.

Sample code below:

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class Service {
   final static RestTemplate REST = new RestTemplate()

   def get() {      
    def list = REST.getForObject(url, clazzObject, map) 
    list
}
}
```

Integration test class

```
class RackServiceIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
     def service = new Service()

     void testApp(){
        setup:
        def testValues = ["name1", "name2"]
        service.metaClass.get = {String url, Class clazz, Map map -> testValues}

        when:
        def val = service.get()

        then:
        val.get(0) == 'name1'

    }
}
```

Instead of mocking the rest call, it actually makes the original rest call and gets the values from database. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: When you need to mock a private method it most often indicates bad design. Why you need to mock this method? Instead external service should be mocked.

Comment: The private method has the logic to make external service call. I would like to bypass that service and mock that by returning predefined values.

Comment: That's not good decision, mocking the service is much better idea.

Comment: Thank you @Opal. I have updated the test code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Opal already commented - instead of mocking an internal detail of the service (like the private method) you should cut off the external dependencies. But this is of course only true for unit-test-kind style of testing. Depending on what your goals are for the test you could either cut off the external stuff or do the actual call and work with a mock on the other side (both are two valid tests in different levels).

When you want to mock before do the wire transfer, you should do it with a mock instance of RestTemplate (which means, that you have to let it be injectable - which is a good idea anyway, because it is an external dependency). But there is a even better solution provided by spring: `MockRestServiceServer`

```
class RackServiceIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
 def service = new Service()
   def 'service calls the external http resource correct and returns the value'() {
    setup: 'create expectations on the http interactions'
    MockRestServiceServer mockServer  = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(service.REST)
    mockServer.expect(requestTo("/customers/123")).andRespond(withSuccess("Hello world", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

    when: 'service gets called'
    def val = service.get()

    then: 'http interactions were successful given the assertions above'
    mockServer.verify();

    and: 'your other assertions'
    val.get(0) == 'name1'

  }
}
```

For more information see the [spring testing documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-client)